# Calculate with units

Tags: output-formatting

If I want to calculate with units, for example using Pythagoras theorem, I would do this:

```
c = Sqrt[(3m)^2 + (5m)^2]
```

The result will be `5 Sqrt[m^2]`.

How can I define that `m = Sqrt[m^2]` and so forth?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post by Jon McLoone:

[Automatic Physical Units in Mathematica](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/09/automatic-physical-units-in-mathematica/)

where he explains how to use this package:

[Automatic Units](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7655/)

which has over 1000 physical units. Also you can simply use Wolfram|Alpha integration in Mathematica. At the beginning of any input line type single equal sign and see it turn into a large orange equal sign, - then compute:

[image]

Using little plus sign at the top right corner you can do more complicated things, like mixed units computation for mechanical kinetic energy below, giving correct units of Joules:

[image]

Typing equal sign twice you can get a full Wolfram|Alpha query in your notebook with more relevant info:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Assuming[m > 0, Simplify[Sqrt[(3 m)^2 + (5 m)^2]]]
```

> Sqrt[34] m

Or, if you want to have this assumption during your whole session you could define:

```
$Assumptions = {m > 0};
```

Now `Simplify` and any other function accepting the `Assumptions` option will use this assumption:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[(3 m)^2 + (5 m)^2]]
```

> Sqrt[34] m

Comment: `PowerExpand[]` would also be useful here.